# How to escape a character in Write-Output with Powershell?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, escape-characters

I am searching for $software in a list with -Match "$software".
I also want to Write-Output $software to the screen.

In the case of Notepad++ I have to escape the second +.
I've tried
`$software=Notepad+{backtick}+` which errors with `parsing "Notepad++" - Nested quantifier +.`

`Notepad+\\+` which doesn't error but writes Notepad+\\+ with Write-Output

The full code

```
$software="Notepad++"
Check-if-Installed $software    
    
Function Check-if-Installed{
    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$software_to_check
        )
    Write-Output "Checking if $software_to_check is installed"
    if ((gp HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*).DisplayName -Match "$software_to_check" -or 
    (gp HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*).DisplayName -Match "$software_to_check")
    {Write-Output "$software_to_check Installed"
    
   
} else {Write-Output "$software_to_check Not Installed"}
}
```

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1685323/edit) and post the entire code ?

Comment: a) I'd use `Write-Host` instead of `Write-Output`. b) use `-like` instead of `-match` so you don't have to worry about escaping. e.g `.DisplayName -like "*$software_to_check*"`

Comment: @SimonS doesn't answer the question, but solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe be escape the whole variable using curly braces: `if ((gp HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*).DisplayName -Match {$software_to_check} -or 
    (gp HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*).DisplayName -Match {$software_to_check})
    {Write-Output {$software_to_check} Installed`

Comment: [1] DO NOT wrap `$software_to_check` in quotes. that "stringifies" the values in the $Var and can give you odd results. leave it as just the bare $Var. ///// [2] when doing regex tests that contain special regex chars ... _use the `[regex]::Escape()` static method to get around things like `++`. [*grin*] ///// [3] you can also use `-like` if you add leading & trailing `*` wildcards to the search string.

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like that :

---

```
Function Replace-SpecialChars {
    param($InputString)
    $SpecialChars = '[+]'
    $Replacement  = '\+'
    $InputString -replace $SpecialChars,$Replacement
}

Function Check-if-Installed {
param ([parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$software_to_check)
Write-Host "Checking if $software_to_check is installed"
$OS_Architecture = $env:PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE
if($OS_Architecture -eq 'x86') 
{
    #32-bit
    $key = "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*"
}
else
{
    #64-bit
    $key = "HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*"
}
$software = Replace-SpecialChars -InputString "$software_to_check"
    If((Get-ItemProperty $Key).DisplayName -Match "$software") { 
      Write-Host "$software_to_check is Installed" -Fore Green 
    } 
    else 
    { Write-Host "$software_to_check is not Installed" -Fore Red}
}

$software="Notepad++"
Check-if-Installed $software
# If you want to check within array :
$Software_Array = @("Notepad++","firefox","chrome","Bitdefender","Powershell","7-zip","winrar","winzip","Hackoo")
ForEach ($Soft in $Software_Array) {
    Check-if-Installed $soft
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `-Match` operator uses regular expressions. `Write-Output` takes a literal or an expansion string.

The `Escape` method of the `Regex` class will return a string with all special characters escaped. Use this string for athe match operation.

```
$software = 'Notepad++'
    
Function Check-if-Installed{
    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$software_to_check
        )
    $UnInstall64 = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*'
    $UnInstall32 = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*'

    Write-Output "Checking if $software_to_check is installed"

    $MatchString = [Regex]::Escape($software_to_check)

    If (( gp $UnInstall64 ).DisplayName -Match $MatchString -or 
        ( gp $UnInstall32 ).DisplayName -Match $MatchString )
    {
        Write-Output "$software_to_check Installed"
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Output "$software_to_check Not Installed"
    }
}

# In PowerShell, you have to define a fucdtion before you refence it.

Check-if-Installed $software
```

---

P.S.

While wildcards are easy to use in paths. they don't seem to be the most efficeint way to deal with registry paths. Try the following code to test three different methods of getting the same data:

```
$UnInstall64  = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*'
$UnInstall64B = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall'

Measure-Command  { (gp $Uninstall64).DisplayName }

Measure-Command  { (gci $Uninstall64B | gp).DisplayName }

Measure-Command  { (gci $Uninstall64B).ForEach({ $_.GetValue('DisplayName') }) }
```

May be trivial in this case, but can make a big difference when digging through something like `HKCR\CLSID\...`.